# Is it correct to store JWT (gem 'devise-jwt') in LocalStorage? If yes, how can i clear LocalStorage if token expires?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, jwt

When the token expired, this token is still in localStorage and I cannot do anything. Will be good, if I can automatically clear localStorage when the token expires?

[jwt localStorage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bF7TX.png)

Comment: I would prefer [HTTP cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies). If you can't or you don't want to, i would rather use [Session Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) because _the difference is that while **data in localStorage doesn't expire**, data in sessionStorage is cleared when the page session ends_.

Comment: @Jax-p Thanks, I'll go to investigate